# Initializing Objective-C property in child class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Apple recommends that you access the instance variables that back your properties directly, rather than using a getter/setter, when initializing a class:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

However, it seems that instance variables backing a property in a parent class are not accessible in the child class; why is this the case? I'm extending a class in a library (Cocos2d) where not all the instance variables are initialized in the parent class init function. For example:

```
---

@interface parentClass

@property (assign) int myProperty;

----

@interface childClass : parentClass

----

@implementation childClass

- (id) init {
  // this doesn't work.
  _myProperty = 0;
}
```

Comment: `@property` are prefixed with an underscore in classes, I guess you should write `_myProperty = 0;`

Comment: You might not know the property ivar name used in the superclass implentation. You can then initialize with self.propertyname =

Comment: Sorry for the type. I am in fact using _myProperty, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access instance variables from your superclass in a subclass, so `_variableName` will also not work.

You `init` method will look something like this

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        // subclass initialisation goes here
    }
}
```

Once `[super init]` returned an object, the superclass part of your object is initialised, so it should be safe to access properties using their getters and setters:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.superClassProperty = aValue;
    }
}
```

Have a look at ["Don't message self in Objective-C init" on QualityCoding](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/) on when to use instance variables and when to call methods (e.g. property accessors). In short: Only call methods when your object is in a consistent state.

**Why can't you access backing ivars?**

A property declaration in a header declares a getter and setter for the property, a backing ivar is created when the property is synthesised, which happens in the implementation. (Automatic and manual synthesis doesn't make a difference). The ivar declaration is therefor only visible in the implementation. If you absolutely have to access ivars in subclasses, you have to make them public (or semi-public by putting them in a header for subclassing only).

Comment: Let me clarify. I seem to be able to access instances variables in certain cases, like if in the implementation of the parent class a property is synthesized and explicitly backed (@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty). Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks. I understand now the general message that I should only be using getters and setters when the object is in a consistent state. However, I'm just confused about why I CAN (not should) sometimes access the instance variables of a parent in a child class. To give you an example from the Cocos2d library, the class CCParticleMeteor in CCParticleExamples.m accesses instance variable _startColor in method initWithTotalParticles:, but that instance variable is declared in CCParticleSystem, which is the grandparent of that class.

Comment: `_startColor` is declared in the header (CCParticleSystem.h) and then referenced in the `@synthesize` in the implementation (CCParticlesSystem.m).

Comment: Correct. But that should rarely (if not never) be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Two last questions: (1)Say I make a property myProperty in my header, and let it be automatically synthesized. If I also create an ivar named _myProperty (without explicitly synthesizing), will myProperty be backed by _myProperty? (2) In general, how do you make an ivar public?

Comment: (1) yes, (2) In general, you don't make ivars public

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your parentClass.h:

```
@interface parentClass {
  @protected
  int _myProperty;
}
@property (nonatomic) int myProperty;
```

Then, in your childClass.m

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _myProperty = aValue;
    }
}
```

iVars are declared as protected by default, so your children can see them. There is no need to write @protected. And for your information you can also declare them as @private or @public.

But if you write the protected iVar in a private interface in your parentClass.m, this will not work and the children will not see it.